# Bash script if statement returning incorrect result while bash -x works

Tags: bash, shell-script, process-management

I have a simple bash script that checks if a program is running and actions accordingly.

```
#!/bin/bash

check_running=$(pgrep -x redshift)

if [[ -n "$check_running" ]]; then
    echo "1"
    else
        echo "0"
fi
```

If I execute the script normally (./script) then it will always return 1. But if I use "bash -x script" then it returns the correct outcome

```
❯ bash -x redshift
++ pgrep -x redshift
+ check_running=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ echo 0
0
```

I have a similar script checking if openvpn is running and it returns the correct value via regular execution.

Here it is in full:

```
~/.config/polybar/scripts
❯ pgrep -x redshift

~/.config/polybar/scripts
❯ ./redshift       
1

~/.config/polybar/scripts
❯ bash -x redshift 
++ pgrep -x redshift
+ check_running=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ echo 0
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `./redscript`, `pgrep -x redscript` will match that script's process, so `check_running` will have a PID. You can put a `set -x` in the script, or use `#! /bin/bash -x` as the shebang, to verify this.

Comment: Isn't that what the -x flag in pgrep is used for?

Comment: For a script started as `./redshift`, the complete command line is just `redshift`. `pgrep -x redshift` will match that.

Comment: `psgrep -x` find matching for the whole line; while `./redshift` and `bash -x redshift` are one same thing in some logical way, they are two different things in term of `psgrep -x`.

Comment: Of course it will, that makes sense now. The check script is called redshift and the program in /usr/bin is called redshift. Probably a bad idea to do in general..